# How to list all users access on folder?

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I using Powershell NTFS module. My goal is to list all users have access on a folder.

When i using:

```
Get-Item "\\SharedFolder\MyFolder" | Get-NTFSAccess
```

I see some user and 'user group" and I would like see all user inside this groups.

For example all user access on MyFolder are:

```
Bob
John
Technician_group
```

Technician_group contain:

```
Jennifer
Andrea
```

My goal is to have this result :

```
Get-Item "\\SharedFolder\MyFolder" | Get-NTFSAccess
Bob
John
Jennifer
Andrea
```

Comment: Did you tried the cmdlet get-acl?

Comment: Yes, but same Get-NTFSAccess i see Users and group.  It's will be nice if i can see user+user group member.

Comment: With (Get-ADGroupMember "GroupName" -Recursive).Name you can get the name of the group members

Answer (score 2):

Iv'e found 2 commands that will give the answer, but I dont have the skill to stitch them together. I'm sure someone can help with that.

Identify the group permissions on a folder
PS> get-acl G:\Sales\ | ForEach-Object { $_.Access } |Format-List IdentityReference

For a security group, identify all active members
PS> Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Sales Admin" -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties "Enabled" | Format-List Name

I believe Get-ADGroupMember is only available in Windows 10 and Server 2016